# Any method that can show the time evolution of a open many body system?

Tags: many-body, time-evolution, open-quantum-systems

the master equation seems is a choice but this method seems only give a mean field result which can not show obviously the effect of specific interaction between particles. So, I am wondering is there any other method that can show the time evolution of a many body open system driven by interaction in the system?

Comment: by "show" do you mean "compute"? The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_quantum_system) mentions a number of methods to solve open system dynamics

Answer (score -1):

Just to give a little more precise answer search for **QUAMTUM MASTER EQUATION** in david tongs quantum me notes. Also MIT lecture notes on **QUANTUM RADIATION INTERACTION** by P. CAPPELLARO
Both of them required zero prerequisites as far I can see.